# show an image1 behind another image2 in the white part of the image2 xcode ,objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image, draw

I have an image that contain a form (cercle withe bordure ) and I want to draw a camembert progressing under the image and show the camembert progression in the white part of the image

I succeed to draw a camembert (circulaire)  without this image but when I draw the image 
the camembert is totaly covered by the image and I cannot see it on the white part of the image

So my question is how can I show  a form or what ever behind an image in the white part of the image

Answer (score 0):

The top image needs to be transparent where you want to see through it. You'll also need to make your image view not be opaque so that it will draw other views behind it:

- On iOS, you can set the `opaque` property of your UIImageView to `NO`
- On the Mac, you'll need to subclass NSImageView to return `NO` from `-isOpaque`

Comment: think you for the response but I'm a beginner can you give me an example with code !! I don't understand how I can do it

Comment: What platform are you developing for?